# Issue getting distinct values from column into array from mySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to get the unique values in a specific column into an array, so I can validate what's being sent to my PHP to avoid mySQL injection. Here's what I have:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$sessiont = 'SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=6000';
$fixed = $dbh->query($sessiont);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select distinct `category` as cats FROM {$table}");
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$categories = explode(",",$row["cats"]);

$whatCategory = isset($_GET['category']) ? "{$_GET['category']}" : '';

if (in_array($whatCategory, $categories))
{
    $sql = "select distinct value from {$table} where category = '{$whatCategory}';";

    $result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
else
{
    echo ("unauthorized!");
}
```

Right now, this is only giving me the first value in the column `category` and isn't creating a valid array, which means I'm getting "unauthorized!"

If I make a replacement to the above for `$categories` like this:

```
$categories = array ('category1','category2','category3');
```

Then it works (i.e., I don't get `unauthorized!`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally untested but looking at the sql you use initially you will get several rows probably containing 'cats' rather than one field with comma separated values of cats. Perhaps you would wish to use group_concat( `category` ) as 'cats' to return a single row?

You then go on to test whether '$whereCategory' is in the array of categories. I see no previous mention of $whereCategory!

Comment: Had to change it to this:
`$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select group_concat( category ) as 'cats' FROM {$table}");` and it works. However, each category has multiple rows in my table and the array that is created has as many entries as there are rows for a given column (e.g.,"category1","category1","category1","category1", ,"category2","category2"). Any way to ensure I only get one entry per category?

Comment: Probably use array_unique on final array before passing it to the logic test ( in_array( $whatCategory, $categories ) )

Comment: Tried adding to array_unique to this which builds the array, but it only includes one category (first one alphabetically): `$categories = explode(",",$row["cats"]);`. I guess I'm not sure how to integrate array_unique into my specific code.

Comment: nevermind...I got it. I had made a change to my sql statement that broke everything and didn't change it back. Adding the array_unique to this worked perfectly: `$categories = explode(",",$row["cats"]);` 
Thanks.

Comment: or... $categories = array_unique( explode(",",$row["cats"]) ); ??